# upload images in Django save onlyto folder but not saving to mysql database

Tags: django, django-imagekit

I need  help my code below save image to folder but not saving to mysql database. pls i dont knw where am getting it wrong.

VIEW.PY

def indeximg(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":


    form=ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    
    
    if form.is_valid():
    
    
       form.save()
       
       
       return redirect('uploadok')
else:


   form = ImageForm()
   
   
   return render(request, 'indeximg.html', {'form': form})
```

def uploadok(request):

```
return HttpResponse(' upload successful')
```

IN MODEL.PY

class Image(models.Model):

```
caption=models.CharField(max_length=100)


image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

Comment: Django model `ImageField` creates a column that holds a string value. This string is the URL to the image location on the file system. Images uploaded are not saved to the database. Instead, they're saved to the folder you indicate when creating your image model.

Comment: Django only save img url, and few more info in db. You need to use this url to show these images on ui. Images get saved to media folder as defined in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

From django docs about [ImageFied](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField)

> `ImageField` instances are created in your database as `varchar` columns with a default max length of 100 characters. As with other fields, you can change the maximum length using the `max_length` argument.

Comment: i have change the maximum length still not saving the name to database . below is my 
MODEL.PY
class Image(models.Model):
    caption=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',max_length=500)

Comment: `max_length` is The length of the URL allowed to be stored refers to the image given the path specified in `upload_to`.

**NOT** the binary data of the image